# Make agent face other agent upon MoveTo arrival?

Tags: anylogic

I have a warehouse model where "Picker" agents move along the Y-axis to reach the front of a "picking slot" agent.

I would like to make it so that upon arrival in front of the picking slot, the Picker agents face the picking slot.

I am aware of the "Set rotation upon arrival" feature of the MoveTo blocks, but I am having trouble making sense out of it. What sort of value should I input here?

Is it possible to dynamically define the rotation according the the agents' relative location to each other? If so, how should I go about it? Some of the slots are on the left of the picker, and others on the right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the Wholesale Warehouse example in the sample models (help section of AnyLogic). There they use `agent.agent_image.setRotation(-PI)` and then turn it into initial position with `agent_image.setRotation(0)` You can use this dynamically and with **if** conditions in your blocks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked perfectly.